# AS3 + addChild() getting image from library to the stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an `.fla` file with 1 image in the library and 1 `.as` file.

I have linked the image up with the Class name of `libraryImages` and Base class is `flash.display.BitmapData`.

This is my `AS`:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Banner extends MovieClip { 
        var defaultImage:libraryImages = new libraryImages(469, 60);
        var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(defaultImage);
        addChild(myImage);
    }
}
```

I am getting two errors:

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.
1120: Access of undefined property myImage.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the constructor, oops.

It has to be

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Banner extends MovieClip { 

        public function Banner()
        {
            var defaultImage:libraryImages = new libraryImages(469, 60);
            var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(defaultImage);
            addChild(myImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can tell, this is my 1st project :P. Cheers.

Comment: Don't worry, Colin, we were all beginners once.